# Update first 8 rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to update the first 8 rows in a table each time the page refreshes.
The way I have tried to approach this is using the query below but it updates all the rows in the table.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong or is there a better way to do this.

```
 $query_conf_update = "
 UPDATE ConfBookings2017 
    Set Screen1
  WHERE HotelID ='".$HotelID."' 
    AND RecordID IN (
     SELECT RecordID FROM (
       SELECT RecordID 
         FROM ConfBookings2017 
        WHERE HotelID ='".$HotelID."'
        ORDER 
           BY RoomFromTime DESC  
        LIMIT 0, 8
     ) tmp
 )";
```

Comment: Set screen1 ? Really?

Comment: define "all". how many updatable rows in the table? if it's just 10, then one extra refresh will update them all. also `Set Screen1` doesn't seem to be correct SQL. Also, why such a strange requirement at all?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And of course .... Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 1):

Single-table UPDATE allows ORDER BY and LIMIT, so subquery is excess:

```
UPDATE ConfBookings2017 
Set Screen1 = 'new value'       /* or parameter placeholder */
WHERE HotelID ='".$HotelID."'   /* recommendation - convert to parameter */
/* AND another conditions, for example, Screen1 != 'new value' */
ORDER BY RoomFromTime DESC  
LIMIT 8;
```